Kibana report generation - Spring Boot
I am trying to automatically download the Kibana report in PDF format.
Following the documentation here : https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/automating-report-generation.html
The issue is, on hitting the path that has been returned by the POST call, it returns JSON data.
But I want the PDF to be downloaded and stored at a location.
JSON to PDF seems to be a lengthy process and there's no schema that is fixed for the pdf report json that we will get every time.
And apparently it requires schema to be fixed for json to pdf conversion in spring boot.
Any better way to do it?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
